# How to remove multiple values of different dictionaries stored in arrays with JSON_REMOVE?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0

I have the following json doc in MYSQL JSON field called `test`:

```json
[
  {"a": "1", "b": "2"},
  {"a": "1", "b": "-2"},
  {"a": "2", "b": "3"},
  {"a": "2", "b": "-3"},
  {"a": "3", "b": "4"}
]
```

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (`test` JSON);

INSERT INTO `test` VALUES
    (JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('a', '1', 'b', '2'),
                JSON_OBJECT('a', '1', 'b', '-2'),
                JSON_OBJECT('a', '2', 'b', '3'),
                JSON_OBJECT('a', '2', 'b', '-3'),
                JSON_OBJECT('a', '3', 'b', '4'))),
    (JSON_ARRAY()),
    (JSON_ARRAY());

SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(`test`, 'all', 1, null, '$[*].a')) `data`
  FROM `test`;

+----------------------+
| data                 |
+----------------------+
| ["$[0].a", "$[1].a"] |
| NULL                 |
| NULL                 |
+----------------------+
```

And I want to remove all dictionaries that have key/value `"a": "1"`.
So I tried this:

```
UPDATE `test`
   SET `test` = JSON_REMOVE(`test`, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(`test`,
                                                             'all', 
                                                             1, 
                                                             null, 
                                                             '$[*].a')));
```

The expected result that I wanted is, but of course it doesn't work:

```
// This is an expected result after update
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(`test`, 'all', 1, null, '$[*].a')) `data`, `test`   FROM `test`;


+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                               
| data                 | test                                                                                                             |                                                                                                               
+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                               
| NULL                 | [{"a": "2", "b": "3"}, {"a": "2", "b": "-3"}, {"a": "3", "b": "4"}] |                                                                                                               
| NULL                 | []                                                                                                               |                                                                                                               
| NULL                 | []                                                                                                               |                                                                                                               
+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note that the mysql version is 8.0

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Recursive CTE* along with `JSON_EXTRACT()` function in order to dynamically generate the indexes, of which don't match `a = 1`, of objects within the array such as

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
 SELECT 0 i
  UNION ALL
 SELECT i + 1 i
   FROM cte
  WHERE i + 1 < ( SELECT JSON_LENGTH(jsdata) FROM `test` )  
)
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata, CONCAT('$[',i,']'))) AS Result
  FROM `test`,
       cte
 WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata, CONCAT('$[',i,'].a')) != "1"
```

provided that the version of the DB is `8+`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ebd24ff869a52e781eaa6ce6844642f)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but doesn't exist nothing less tricky? Btw your solution seems to be really cool and stylish. P.s. Yes the MySQL version is 8+

Comment: I added more information after suggestion of @Akina to make the example more understandable

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH 
-- enumerate rows - unique value per row is needed for reconstruction
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn
    FROM test 
    ),
-- decompose JSON array to separate objects properties, 
-- select only those which does not contain unneeded value
cte2 AS (
    SELECT cte1.*, jsontable.a, jsontable.b
    FROM cte1
    CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(cte1.test, 
                          '$[*]' COLUMNS ( a VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.a',
                                           b VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.b')) jsontable
    WHERE jsontable.a <> 1
    ),
-- reconstruct the array w/o unneeded objects back
cte3 AS (    
    SELECT test, rn, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('a', a, 'b', b)) new_test
    FROM cte2
    GROUP BY test, rn
    )
-- update sourdce table
UPDATE test
JOIN cte3 ON test.test = cte3.test
SET test.test = cte3.new_test;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05e4db09be79152c37b9b482b8bff170

If the table in practice contains primary key or at least unique index then you can simplify the query (`cte1` not needed, final join can be performed by this PK/unique).

Comment: Thank for the code and a complete explanation of it, I really appreciate it.